# Zend Framework - how to fix the path?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-feed

Q. How can i fix this Zend_Feed_Reader?

My error:
Could not load extension: JungleBooksusing Plugin Loader. Check prefix paths are configured and extension exists.

Please kindly check the code from this link(because in stackoverflow paste code is very complex): 
http://gist.github.com/469387

Comment: Is your include_path pointing to the correct library?

Comment: @streetparade: http://gist.github.com/469387
@pekka: yes without this line, no error occur. Zend_Feed_Reader::registerExtension('JungleBooks');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'/var/www/html/zendframework/application/My/FeedReader/Extension', 'My_FeedReader_Extension'
```

You forgot to change the examples codes to whatever it is you are really using. 
Thats like

```
('path/to')
```

Its to show you where you put your own code.

Comment: File name /var/www/html/zendframework/application/My/FeedReader/Extension/JungleBooks/Entry.php i did worked.